# How to select nominator and denominator from textbox in c#?

Tags: c#, textbox

Example -

```
textbox.Text = "456/789"; 
var nominator = 456; 
var denominator = 789
```

How could I code this in c# ?

1. Also, how could I make one number from elements of array.  For example, {1,5,7,6} would become 1576.

And now, i have such bad idea, but i wont to know: if I have int number in nominator, I will do one method from my1.cs, if I have double number in nominator/denominator I will do method from another class called my2.cs . How I may code IF, if (number = int;bla bla bla...), if (number = double; bla bla bla...)

Comment: These are two questions really.  You should post them separately, as they are both good questions.

Comment: And now, i have such bad idea, but i wont to know: if I have int number in nominator, I will do one method from my1.cs, if I have double number in nominator/denominator I will do method from another class called my2.cs . How I may code IF, if (number = int;bla bla bla...), if (number = double; bla bla bla...)

Comment: Note that a "nominator" is someone who proposes that another person stand for election. The top half of a fraction is a "numerator". The bottom half is the "denominator".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

1.

```
string[] numdenom = textbox.Text.Split('/');
var numerator = numdenom[0];
var denominator = numdenom[1];
```

2.

```
string[] digits = new string[] { "1","5","7","6" };
string number = string.Join(string.Empty, digits);
int numberValue = int.Parse(number); // or int.TryParse if you prefer
```

Comment: And now, i have such bad idea, but i wont to know: if I have int number in nominator, I will do one method from my1.cs, if I have double number in nominator/denominator I will do method from another class called my2.cs . How I may code IF, if (number = int;bla bla bla...), if (number = double; bla bla bla...)

Answer (score 3):

```
string[] input = textbox.Text.Split('/');
var nominator = input[0];
var denominator = input[1];
```

Assuming you will always have the input in that format.

String.Join will smash them back together for you.  Just don't use a separator.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx

Comment: thanks, this is :bool flag = true;
            int co = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < dr1len; i++)
            {
                if (flag == true)
                {
                    an[i] = textBox1.Text[i];
                    if (Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text[i]) == "/")
                    {
                        flag = false;
                        an[i] = Convert.ToChar("\0");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    aden[co] = textBox1.Text[i];
                    co++;
                }
            }

Comment: @Andy Don't you first have to use .ToString() on the values / convert to string[] to use string.Join on it?  Per your link, Join takes (string, string[])

Comment: @Chuck, there is an overload that works with object[] - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350.aspx

Comment: @Andy, thank you Andy.  Deleted my post since it's a less helpful duplicate.

Comment: And now, i have such bad idea, but i wont to know: if I have int number in nominator, I will do one method from my1.cs, if I have double number in nominator/denominator I will do method from another class called my2.cs . How I may code IF, if (number = int;bla bla bla...), if (number = double; bla bla bla...)

Comment: You could probably figure it out based on searching for the . but honestly I would write one method that takes the nominator as a string and converts to a double and go from there.  An int would get covered by that.

Answer (score 3):

## 1)

```
var value = textbox.Text.Split('/');
var nominator = value[0];
var denominator = value[1];
```

## 2)

```
String.Join
```

Comment: And now, i have such bad idea, but i wont to know: if I have int number in nominator, I will do one method from my1.cs, if I have double number in nominator/denominator I will do method from another class called my2.cs . How I may code IF, if (number = int;bla bla bla...), if (number = double; bla bla bla...)

Answer (score 1):

For the numerator and denominator, you could use "substring" or "split" to split/select the numbers before and after the "/".

For the array, you could loop through it, and add each number to a string, then convert that string to an integer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: And now, i have such bad idea, but i wont to know: if I have int number in nominator, I will do one method from my1.cs, if I have double number in nominator/denominator I will do method from another class called my2.cs . How I may code IF, if (number = int;bla bla bla...), if (number = double; bla bla bla...)

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, splitting the nominator and denominator I would use simple substring methods:

```
textbox.Text.substring(0, textbox.text.indexof("\"); //denominator
textbox.text.substring(textbox.text.indexof("\") + 1); //numerator
```

For the second, I'd suggest using a foreach loop to loop through each item in the array and concatenate onto a string object.  I say a string object so you don't end up adding the numbers together, getting 19 instead of 1576.

Comment: And now, i have such bad idea, but i wont to know: if I have int number in nominator, I will do one method from my1.cs, if I have double number in nominator/denominator I will do method from another class called my2.cs . How I may code IF, if (number = int;bla bla bla...), if (number = double; bla bla bla...)

Comment: With C# you'll have to assume, and cast your variables to be the same, so if you have a double/int you'll need to convert the int to a double.  If you are using .Net 4.0 you can use ToDouble as shown here [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayes1wa5.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for the numerator and denominator.

```
var parts = textbox.Text.Split('/');
var numerator = parts[0];
var denominator = parts[1];
```

As for combining the elements of an array, you'll need to convert and build up a string, then convert it back to a number.

```
var numbers = new[] {1, 5, 7, 6};
var builder = new StringBuilder();
for each (var i in numbers) {
  builder.Append(i);
}
var result = int.Parse(builder.ToString());
```

Comment: And now, i have such bad idea, but i wont to know: if I have int number in nominator, I will do one method from my1.cs, if I have double number in nominator/denominator I will do method from another class called my2.cs . How I may code IF, if (number = int;bla bla bla...), if (number = double; bla bla bla...)